# Array Tally Chart

Tags: pascal

I'm trying to create a Tally Chart based on values stored in array.

I know it is possible to do this in Python, but is there a way to do this in Pascal by keeping the amount of coding to a minimum?

```
var numbers:array [0..9] of integer;
    Sum,aNumber, count,count2:integer;
    Average:real=0;


begin
randomize;

// Put 10 Random numbers into an array
for count:= 0 to 9 do
  begin
  aNumber:=Random(10)+1;
  numbers[count]:=aNumber
  end; 

// Show a Tally

  begin
    for count:= 0 to 9 do
      writeln(numbers[count] * '£');

    writeln;
  end;

readln;

end.
```

I simply want to present the outcome of the array by showing all possible values.  E.g. If my array had the following random values between 1 and 10:  3,3,8,8,9  it should show:
1-
2-
3- II
4-
..
8- II
9- I
10-

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way would be another for loop:

```
for count := 0 to 9 do 
begin
    for i := 1 to numbers[count] do
        write('£');
    writeln;
end
```

If you can settle for just one character at the right position, you could use something like:

```
for count := 0 to 9 do
    writeln('£' : numbers[count]);
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't make it clear enough in the problem description. The tally should go from 1 to 10.  If the following three random numbers were generated [3,3,6], it should look like: 1-   2-   3-II   4-   5-   6-I   7-   ETC.  Do i need to create a new array to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Think it works now... i created a Function to return the number of instances in each element.  That result helps me to know the no. of iterations for each number.

```
Function TallyCount(x:integer):integer;
var i,TotalCount:integer;
begin
i:=0;
TotalCount:=0;
for i := 0 to 9 do
    begin
    if numbers[i] = x then
       TotalCount:=TotalCount +1;
    end;
result:=Totalcount;
end;
```

Comment: You don't need to zero 'i' at the beginning of this function. Also, replace all instances of 'TotalCount' with 'result' and then you can lose the final assignment as well.